# Navbar does not respond when clicked on mobile phone media

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hey fellow Devs could you please help me solve this one issue that prevents me from finishing this website. Someone view https://hcbcke.netlify.app/ in smart phone view on their browser and help me solve why the responsive menu icon is not responding when clicked. You can download the source code at https://github.com/kimanicharles911/hope_city_bible_church . Below is the HTML code.
[image: image of website]

```html
<nav class="nav-primary" aria-label="Main">
            <div class="wrap">
              <div class="responsive-menu-icon"></div>
              <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu genesis-nav-menu menu-primary responsive-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-116" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-103 current_page_item menu-item-116">
                  <a href="#" aria-current="page"><span>Home</span></a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-115" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-115">
                  <a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-112" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-112">
                  <a href="#"><span>Music</span></a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-111" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-111">
                  <a href="#"><span>Training</span></a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-9230" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-9230">
                  <a href="#"><span>Blog</span></a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-3048" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom social-icon facebook menu-item-3048">
                  <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.facebook.com/hcbcke/">
                    <span>
                      <i class="icon-2x icon-facebook"></i>
                      <span class="fa-hidden">Facebook</span>
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-3049" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom social-icon twitter menu-item-3049">
                  <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="#">
                    <span>
                      <i class="icon-2x icon-twitter"></i>
                      <span class="fa-hidden">Twitter</span>
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-3050" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom social-icon youtube menu-item-3050">
                  <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="#">
                    <span>
                      <i class="icon-2x icon-youtube"></i>
                      <span class="fa-hidden">YouTube</span>
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-6279" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom social-icon instagram menu-item-6279">
                  <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="#">
                    <span>
                      <i class="icon-2x icon-instagram"></i>
                      <span class="fa-hidden">Instagram</span>
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-8331" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8331">
                  <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="#">
                    <span>
                      <i class="fab fa-spotify icon-2x"></i>
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-8332" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8332">
                  <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="#">
                    <span>
                      <i class="fab fa-apple icon-2x"></i>
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-5105" class="bop-nav-search menu-item menu-item-type-search menu-item-object- menu-item-5105">
                  <form class="bop-nav-search menu-item menu-item-type-search menu-item-object- menu-item-5105" role="search" method="get" action="#">
                    <label>
                      <span class="screen-reader-text">Search</span>
                      <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder value name="s" title>
                    </label>
                    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">
                  </form>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
```

Comment: I would question how does `responsive-menu-icon` react with the menu? Are you using JavaScript? This isn't a standard bootstrap class. You can use Boostrap's own responsive menu that will give you a hamburger menu. Try looking at the documents here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might some conflict with js file with jQuery file. Make sure that you have included the latest jQuery script before the bootstrap js script. You have to include script in order like this-

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If jQuery comes later then javaScript functions will not work.